# UITableView scrolling becomes choppy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with paging enabled. At first I can scroll very smoothly between cells. However, after scrolling back and forth a few times, it becomes rather choppy. Am I not creating/reusing my cells properly?

```
-  (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cash-Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40, cell.frame.size.width-40, cell.frame.size.width-40)];
    Purchase *purch = (Purchase *)self.purchases[indexPath.row];
    [image setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:purch.image]];
    image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    image.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self setMaskTo:image byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight];
    [cell addSubview:image];

    UIView *price = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40+cell.frame.size.width-40, cell.frame.size.width-40, 60)];
    UILabel *priceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, price.frame.size.width, price.frame.size.height)];
    [priceLabel setText:@"$10.0"];
    [priceLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [priceLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:25.0f]];
    [self setMaskTo:price byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft|UIRectCornerBottomRight];
    [price addSubview:priceLabel];
    [price setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [cell addSubview:price];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: *Please* use a custom cell. You are adding views to the cell every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is being called.

Comment: @duci9y is exactly correct, you are doing way too much in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. A custom cell can trim that code down to just a few lines Check my response to this question, its in C# but shouldn't be too hard to port over: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542205/sigsegv-error-ios-uigesturerecognizer-on-uitableview

Comment: You have left out the bit of code that constructs your table cell. I assume you're passing the reuse identifier there as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reuse them then make sure you add the content to your `UITableViewCell` only once and on reusing it just update it (e.g. update the image and the price accordingly).

Otherwise, what you get with your implementation is adding subviews price and image everytime `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` gets called. Just try debugging the number of subviews your cell has to see if I am right.

You could go this way:

```
if ( ! [cell viewWithTag: 1])
{
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40, cell.frame.size.width-40, cell.frame.size.width-40)];
    image.tag = 1;

    image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    image.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self setMaskTo:image byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight];
    [cell addSubview:image];
}

if ( ! [cell viewWithTag: 2])
{
    UIView *price = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40+cell.frame.size.width-40, cell.frame.size.width-40, 60)];
    UILabel *priceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, price.frame.size.width, price.frame.size.height)];
    priceLabel.tag = 2;

    [priceLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [priceLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:25.0f]];
    [self setMaskTo:price byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft|UIRectCornerBottomRight];
    [price addSubview:priceLabel];
    [price setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [cell addSubview:price];
}
Purchase *purch = (Purchase *)self.purchases[indexPath.row];
UIImage *image = [cell viewWithTag: 1];
[image setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:purch.image]];

UILabel *priceLabel = [cell viewWithTag: 2];
[priceLabel setText:@"$10.0"];
```

Comment: how would I go about doing this then?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is being called each time the cell comes into the view.  Add the images to an array (in `viewDidLoad` or somewhere), and you'll get a smoother result.

Answer (score 0):

You are not reusing the cells, which causes the lag/choppy scrolling.

suggestion:

```
 -  (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cash-Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   if(cell == nil){

      UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40, cell.frame.size.width-40, cell.frame.size.width-40)];
      Purchase *purch = (Purchase *)self.purchases[indexPath.row];
      [image setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:purch.image]];
      image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
      image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
      image.clipsToBounds = YES;
      image.tag = 10;
     [self setMaskTo:image byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:image];

     UIView *price = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40+cell.frame.size.width-40, cell.frame.size.width-40, 60)];
     UILabel *priceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, price.frame.size.width, price.frame.size.height)];
    [priceLabel setText:@"$10.0"];
    [priceLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [priceLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:25.0f]];
    [self setMaskTo:price byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft|UIRectCornerBottomRight];
    [price addSubview:priceLabel];
    [price setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    price.tag = 11;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:price];


 }

//update the value here

  UIImageView *imgV = (UIImageView *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:10];
  // update the imageView here
  //imgV.image = image

  UIView *vv = (UIView *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:11];
  // Update the UIView here
  //vv.text = @"text here";


 //Put setselection style here to allow the cell to be loaded before setting the property value
  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

  return cell;
}
```